# Jenkins-cli's set-build-parameter command not working anymore, how to modify the value of a build parameter across build steps?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

In our Jenkins job, we need to sent an email containing a url in a post-build step (we also post the url to a Slack channel, but that's just about the same thing).  The value of the url is dependent on the result of the build.  Modification to an environment variable doesn't persist across build step.  Writing the url to a file in one step and reading it in another is not an option either since the email/slack plugin has no ability of shell script execution.  As a result, we've been using build parameter to solve this issue and the `set-build-parameter` command of jenkins-cli works fine.

After a recent upgrade of Jenkins (we're now at `2.75`), `set-build-parameter` fails to work anymore.  It reports the following error:

`ERROR: Failed to identify the build being executed`

According to Jenkins-cli's help command, `set-build-parameter` seems to be deprecated:

```
set-build-parameter
    Update/set the build parameter of the current build in progress. [deprecated]
```

So, what's the correct way to modify the value of a build parameter across build steps in the latest version of Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I frequently manipulate build parameters in shell script blocks, you have to edit them, save them in a file f. e.:

```
 buildParamter=true>variable.txt
```

Now you can use the [envInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and reference the the newly created file.